# 5 column ROW with long text in Bootstrap 4

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, twitter-bootstrap-4

I know how bootstrap 4 is working with `col` instead of `col-xs` but the issue I am facing is that when the text within the column is too long to accommodate on a small screen device, the columns start to stack below each other. Is there any way to prevent this and fix the col width to 1/5 of the screen and just cut off the extra text.
Try the below code and compress your browser width.

```
<div class="container-fluid">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col">some loong loong loong loong loong text</div>
    <div class="col">some loong loong loong loong loong text</div>
    <div class="col">some loong loong loong loong loong text</div>
    <div class="col">some loong loong loong loong loong text</div>
    <div class="col">some loong loong loong loong loong text</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `text-truncate` class. This will prevent the text inside the columns from wrapping and use ellipsis (`...`) when the text is too long.

https://www.codeply.com/go/rGFZfVlidi

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col text-truncate">some loong loong loong loong loong text</div>
        <div class="col text-truncate">some loong loong loong loong loong text</div>
        <div class="col text-truncate">some loong loong loong loong loong text</div>
        <div class="col text-truncate">some loong loong loong loong loong text</div>
        <div class="col text-truncate">some loong loong loong loong loong text</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Alternatively, `text-nowrap` could be used if you don't want `...`. Read more on [text wrapping and overflow](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/text/#text-wrapping-and-overflow) in Bootstrap 4.

Answer (score 3):

You can avoid the wrap by add `flex-nowrap`

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" >
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row flex-nowrap">
    <div class="col">some loong loong loong loong loong text</div>
    <div class="col">some loong loong loong loong loong text</div>
    <div class="col">some loong loong loong loong loong text</div>
    <div class="col">some loong loong loong loong loong text</div>
    <div class="col">some loong loong loong loong loong text</div>
  </div>
</div>
```